# React Native App crashes when I want to create an 'APK'

Tags: react-native, crash

I have developed a mobile application (primarily for learning) using React Native, and as you can see in the image, everything works perfectly fine in the development environment, and the app runs smoothly.

However, when I come to generate the output with the 'apk' format using 'eas' and install it anywhere, the application crashes after the splash screen (it exits abruptly).

I'm looking for someone who has good experience in this field and can guide me.

I would appreciate it if you could introduce me to someone if you know of anyone.

Thank you.

A very minor error seems to be present due to my unfamiliarity with the environment, which has eluded my sight.